# Возможно ли перенаправить юзера на другую страницу, например, по нажатию кнопки другим юзером?

Tags: веб-программирование

Пишу веб сервис, суть заключается в том, что группа юзеров одновременно проходит один тест. Этот процесс контролирует так называемый администратор. Соответственно, администратор видит список текущих пользователей. Возможно ли выбрать из списка конкретных пользователей и перенести их на страницу тестирования?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так. По нажатию кнопки у администратором в БД поле юзера пихается ссылка на тест. Соответственно у юзера это поле проверяется на каждой странице и переводит его на сгенерированную ссылку